# How can I figure out which Template (class) is being used based on the URL?

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

For example, if my URL is "/" how can I tell in the Application controller which template I am using to render (for example "app/views/index.scala.html")?

UPDATE to my Question:
I have an AJAX call which is passed a URL like "localhost:9000/bob";. In the Controller, I want to find out which template was used returned by the controller method which generated/s "localhost:9000/bob";.

Maybe this is not even possible with Play?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MariusSoutier I have this demo project described on my blog: http://www.poornerd.com/2013/05/03/wysiwyg-editing-of-play-framework-templates-with-the-aloha-editor/  -> I want to know which scala template to "edit" based on the URL passed to the controller in the AJAX request.

Comment: So I guess you have found a solution? Anyway, I wrote an answer with the approach I'd take.

Answer (score 0):

The templates get rendered to normal classes, which you can call.
You just say which template you want in the `Action`.

In **Scala**:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
}
```

In **Java**:

```
public static Result index() {
  return ok(views.html.index.render("Your new application is ready."));
}
```

Also have a look at the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Home). You'll find a tutorial there for building a simple first Todo list application. ([Scala version](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaTodoList), [Java version](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaTodoList))

Comment: I got that, but that was not my question.  I have an AJAX call which is passed a URL like "http://localhost:9000/bob".  In the Controller, I want to find out which template was used returned by the controller method which generated/s "http://localhost:9000/bob".  Maybe this is not even possible with Play?

Comment: @poornerd You should update your question then with your detailed problem.

Comment: @poornerd Definitely not out-of-the-box, because rendering template is just a normal method call like any other. In your case, I'd probably keep a map to see which controller method renders which template.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep some sort of context, you could add a parameter to the route, e.g. `/bob?ref=index`, then you know the call happened in the index template. A cookie would be another viable, but less preferable option.

In both cases you could make this readily available to your controller using action composition.